# Is it possible to train a deep learning model using low precision and subsequently fine-tune it with high precision?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Assuming a BERT model is trained on fp16 and then fine-tuned on fp32 for a specific task, would this result in an increase or decrease in accuracy?

It can take less memory on GPU, training time will be reduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to is called mixed-precision training, and it's basically training the model with low-precision floating-point numbers (e.g., fp16) for most of the layers and using high-precision numbers (e.g., fp32) only for certain layers that require more accuracy. Fine-tuning a low-precision model with high precision on accuracy can vary depending on the specific model and task. In some cases, fine-tuning can result in an increase in accuracy, while in other cases it may not. here is a quick and dirty script to try for mixed precision, to see if it is worth trying as a temperature check:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_text as text
import numpy as np
import os
import json
import math
import time

# Set mixed precision policy
policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.Policy('mixed_float16')
tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.set_policy(policy)

# Load BERT model and tokenizer
bert_model_name = 'bert-base-cased'
bert_dir = f'bert_models/{bert_model_name}'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(bert_dir)
bert_model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(bert_dir)

# Define optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5)

# Define loss function
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# Define metrics
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

# Define batch size
batch_size = 32

# Load training data
train_data = tfds.load('glue/mrpc', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size)

# Fine-tune BERT model
epochs = 5
for epoch in range(epochs):
    start_time = time.time()
    metric.reset_states()
    for batch_idx, data in enumerate(train_data):
        input_ids = data['input_ids']
        attention_mask = data['attention_mask']
        token_type_ids = data['token_type_ids']
        labels = data['label']
        
        # Cast input data to mixed precision
        input_ids = tf.cast(input_ids, tf.float16)
        attention_mask = tf.cast(attention_mask, tf.float16)
        token_type_ids = tf.cast(token_type_ids, tf.float16)
        labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float16)
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            outputs = bert_model(input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids)
            loss_value = loss(labels, outputs.logits)
            
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, bert_model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, bert_model.trainable_weights))
        metric.update_state(labels, outputs.logits)
        
    epoch_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}, Loss: {loss_value:.4f}, Accuracy: {metric.result().numpy():.4f}, Time: {epoch_time:.2f}s')
```